# mysql bulk insert referring ID from another table

Tags: mysql, join, insert, bulk

I have two tables:

```
table_user
======================================
UID     UserName
1       UserA
2       UserB
3       UserC


table_score
==============================
UID     Date         Score
2       18/7/2013     100
2       19/7/2013     150
```

I need to bulk insert score history data (thousands of rows) to table_score. The history data consists of UserName, Date and Score only.

What I'm doing is to have my PHP script load the UID of a given UserName from MySQL, add the UID in to the bulk insert SQL and send it back to MySQL. This requires 2 communications between PHP and MySQL. And I repeat the above for another user.

Is it possible to let MySQL insert the date and score, and fill-in the UID automatically based on the given UserName in one SQL?

Comment: `score history` is a table or what ?

Comment: No, score history is thousands of rows to be inserted into table_score. Have updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: what about this ... INSERT  INTO table_score (uid,Date,Score) VALUES  ((SELECT UID FROM table_user WHERE userName='YourUserNAme) ,'2013-07-18',100)

Comment: Are you loading this history data from file? Do you need to evaluate a user id per row, per batch, per file?

Comment: Baju Soman - your solution works for a single row insert, how about bulk insert? say insert 1000 score records for one user. I prefer not to repeat the SELECT for 1000 times.

Comment: Peterm - the data can be in a file with Username, date and score separated by comma. I'm thinking to do a bulk insert (1000 records for the same user) for each user.

Answer (score 0):

**The fastest method** to import massive amount of data for MySql is to use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)

If you were to have a coma delimited file like this

```
"UserB","18/7/2013",100
"UserB","19/7/2013",150
"UserC","20/7/2013",140
```

Then you load it with a query like this

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE table_score 
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' -- or '\r\n' if it's Windows
(@username, @date, @score) 
SET uid =  
    (
      SELECT uid 
        FROM table_user 
       WHERE username = @username
       LIMIT 1
    ),
    date = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%d/%m/%Y'),
    score = @score;
```

Comment: @LazNiko Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?